# django cms Error during Template rendering cms_toolbar

Tags: python, django, .htaccess, django-cms

I have some Issues with my freshly installed django-cms. The base django system is located in my home directory. Gunicorn deploys everything using the following `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:64367/$1 [P]

RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https env=HTTPS
```

When accessing the main page in my Browser the page is working almost fine. But when logging in as admin and reload the main page I get the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /en-us/
Reverse for 'cms_page_unpublish' with arguments '(1, 'en-US')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['en-us/admin/cms/page/([0-9]+)/([a-z\\-]+)/unpublish/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://www.hg3n.com/en-us/
Django Version: 1.8.7
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'cms_page_unpublish' with arguments '(1, 'en-US')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['en-us/admin/cms/page/([0-9]+)/([a-z\\-]+)/unpublish/$']
Exception Location: /home/hg3n/env/django-cms/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 495
Python Executable:  /home/hg3n/env/django-cms/bin/python3.4
Python Version: 3.4.3
Python Path:    
['/home/hg3n/django-cms',
 '/home/hg3n/env/django-cms/bin',
 '/home/hg3n/env/django-cms/lib/python34.zip',
 '/home/hg3n/env/django-cms/lib/python3.4',
 '/home/hg3n/env/django-cms/lib/python3.4/plat-linux',
 '/home/hg3n/env/django-cms/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/package/host/localhost/python-3.4.3/lib/python3.4',
 '/package/host/localhost/python-3.4.3/lib/python3.4/plat-linux',
 '/home/hg3n/env/django-cms/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 25 Dec 2015 21:49:18 +0100
```

at the point:

```
Error during template rendering

...
{% cms_toolbar %}
...
```

Where is the problem in my setup?
The error message is way longer but maybe this is enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in this line

```
Reverse for 'cms_page_unpublish' with arguments '(1, 'en-US')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['en-us/admin/cms/page/([0-9]+)/([a-z\\-]+)/unpublish/$']
```

arguments for cms_page_unpublish include 'en-US' when the only tried ulr template starts with 'en-us'. Make sure you are not using capitals in the names of languages in settings.py